# How to create a Linux desktop icon cross desktop (KDE, GNOME) with xdg-desktop-icon?

Tags: desktop, shortcut, gnome, kde-plasma, xdgutils

I'd like to use the xdg-desktop-icon tool because it can be scripted and works cross desktop (at least on Linux with Gnome and KDE). At least it is supposed to do so according to freedesktop.org. [1](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html)

Made a minimal file: test.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]

Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application

Exec=test
Icon=test

Name=test
```

Used xdg-desktop-icon...

```
xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor test.desktop
```

Exit code is 0. (Success.) But... I do not see any new icons on my desktop. Also not after reboot. This failed on Ubuntu Precise 12.04 with KDE and on Debian Wheezy with KDE.

How to use the xdg-desktop-icon tool correctly?

The problem on KDE has something to do with the desktop settings. Folder view, Newspaper view and so on.

Comment: Just put the `.desktop` file whereever you want it. I don't know what this "install" thing is all about.

Answer (score 1):

`xdg-desktop-icon` relies on `xdg-user-dir` to determine the user desktop directory.  You can check either against that command and the settings of your file manager (or program handling the desktop).

Assuming by default it would be `/home/user/Desktop`, then you have to check the file name there.  If the file is there, then `xdg-desktop-icon` is working as expected.

You have to consider that the icon (`test` in your case) has to be installed separately using `xdg-icon-resource`. That is, if you are not using a stock icon or custom icon already installed or you are not using an absolute path for the icon.

Do not forget that `xdg-desktop-icon` only copies the `.desktop` file in a specific directory. No more no less.

If I am working on ~/myapp directory, I would check by doing:

```
$ xdg-user-dir
/home/user/Desktop
$ ls `xdg-user-dir`/test.desktop
ls: cannot access /home/user/Desktop/test.desktop: No such file or directory
$ xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor test.desktop
$ ls `xdg-user-dir`/test.desktop
/home/user/Desktop/test.desktop
```

Eventually, you can run with any `xdg-` script with:

```
$ XDG_DEBUG_LEVEL=1 xdg-desktop-icon ...
```

Which will give you an extra line telling you where the desktop file was installed.  At this point, if the icon has not been installed, it might appear an ugly default icon.

Comment: The problem on KDE has something to do with the desktop settings. Folder view, Newspaper view and so on.

Comment: hey @JamesMitch, do you know you need the default or another activity that includes the desktop folder view active? The Icon is likely crated in the desktop folder, not directly on the disktop. You might also check the desktop folder in your file-manger manually /home/user/Desktop(Arbeitsfäche in german). This is awkward isn't it?